# What is the difference between below print statements where the cell holds a Numeric / String value?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

What is the difference between below print statements where the cell holds a Numeric / String value ?
    //trying the print the value from an excel cell

```
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
    System.out.println(cell);
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Comment: What is the difference between number and string? did you try looking at the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html)?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the code posted won't compile. Both of them will throw a compile time exception. so, not much difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cell cell = row.getCell(0);`

---

`System.out.println(cell);`

This prints what `cell.toString()` returns. For example [HSSFCell.toString](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_1/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.java?view=markup#l1024):

```
public String toString() {
    switch (getCellTypeEnum()) {
        case BLANK:
            return "";
        case BOOLEAN:
            return getBooleanCellValue()?"TRUE":"FALSE";
        case ERROR:
            return ErrorEval.getText((( BoolErrRecord ) _record).getErrorValue());
        case FORMULA:
            return getCellFormula();
        case NUMERIC:
            //TODO apply the dataformat for this cell
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(this)) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", LocaleUtil.getUserLocale());
                sdf.setTimeZone(LocaleUtil.getUserTimeZone());
                return sdf.format(getDateCellValue());
            }
            return  String.valueOf(getNumericCellValue());
        case STRING:
            return getStringCellValue();
        default:
            return "Unknown Cell Type: " + getCellType();
    }
}
```

---

`System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());`

This will only work if the cell contains a text. Else it throws an exception. See [Cell.getStringCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue--)

---

`System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());`

This will only work if the cell contains numeric content (number or date). Else it throws an exception. See [Cell.getNumericCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue--)

---

Better way is using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html).

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
...
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
String cellContent = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
System.out.println(cellContent);
```

This works for all types of cell content since `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` returns the formatted value of the cell as a `String` regardless of the cell type.